# SQL to find missing numbers in sequence starting from min?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have found several examples of SQL queries which will find missing numbers in a sequence. For example this one:

```
Select T1.val+1 
from table T1 
where not exists(select val from table T2 where T2.val = T1.val + 1);
```

This will only find gaps in an existing sequence. I would like to find gaps in a sequence starting from a minimum.

For example, if the values in my sequence are 2, 4 then the query above will return 3,5.

I would like to specify that my sequence must start at 0 so I would like the query to return 0,1,3,5.

How can I add the minimum value to my query?

- A few answers to questions below:

  - There is no maximum, only a minimum
  - The DB is oracle

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Do you have a known Maximum as well as a Minimum of Zero?

Comment: I'm using oracle. No maximum, only minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite easy in Postgres:

```
select x.i as missing_sequence_value
from (
   select i
   from generate_series(0,5) i -- 0,5 are the lower and upper bounds you want
) x
  left join the_table t on t.val = x.i 
where t.val is null;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/acb07/1

**Edit**

The Oracle solution is a bit more complex because generating the numbers requires a workaround

```
with numbers as (
   select level - 1 as val
   from dual
   connect by level <= (select max(val) + 2 from the_table) -- this is the maximum
), number_range as (
   select val
   from numbers 
   where val >= 0 -- this is the minimum
)
select nr.val as missing_sequence_value
from number_range nr
  left join the_table t on t.val = nr.val
where t.val is null;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71584/4

The idea (in both cases) is to generate a list of numbers you are interested in (from 0 to 5) and then doing an outer join against the values in your table. The rows where the outer join does not return something from your table (that's the condition `where t.val is null`) are the values that are missing.

The Oracle solution requires two common table expressions ("CTE", the "with" things) because you can't add a `where level >= x` in the first CTE that generates the numbers.

Note that the `connect by level <= ...` is relies on an undocumented (and unsupported) way of using `connect by`. But so many people are using that to get a "number generator" that I doubt that Oracle will actually remove this.

Comment: +1 Postgres has so many useful functions, I guess it would be easy to implement this in mssql as well though :)

Comment: No postgres here. I also only want to specify a minimum, no maximum.

I have thought of this sort of query as well:

    SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= max
MINUS
SELECT val FROM table

but I can't figure out how to specify the max value with a query

Comment: Wow, thank you. That actually works. But my SQL skills are no where near understanding that :(

Comment: @bea I added a bit of explanation

Comment: I think getting the sequence is where I'm was/am lost. I took the max calculation from your solution and added it to my attempt like this:

    SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (select max(val) + 1 from the_table)
MINUS
SELECT val FROM the_table

I'm still missing the 0 for some reason.

Comment: @bea: `rownum` always starts at 1. You need to use `rownum - 1` if you want to start a 0 (as I did with `level - 1`. And then you need to do `max() + 2` to accommodate for the `-1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah! Right. I really appreciate you taking the time to show me all this. You have been very helpful.

Comment: This works fine, unless your data starts having thousands or millions of values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it's actually not that slow. I tried it with a table containing ~120.000 rows comparing against a list of values up to 500.000. Took less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to option to use a [common table expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) you can generate a sequence of numbers and use that as the source of numbers.

The variables `@start` and `@end` defines the range of numbers (you could easily use max(val) from yourtable as end instead).

This example is for MS SQL Server (but CTEs is a SQL 99 feature supported by many databases):

```
declare @start int, @end int
select @start=0, @end=5

;With sequence(num) as
(
    select @start as num
        union all
    select num + 1
        from sequence
        where num < @end
)

select * from sequence seq
where not exists(select val from YourTable where YourTable.val = seq.num)
Option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/940dc/2)

Answer (score 2):

Just presenting 2 small variations to suggestions above, both are for Oracle.

---

First is a small variation to one presented by `jpw` using a [recursive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) Common Table Expression (CTE); simply to demonstrate that this technique is also available in Oracle.

```
WITH
      seq (val)
      AS (
            SELECT 0 FROM dual
            UNION ALL
                  SELECT val + 1
                  FROM seq
                  WHERE val < (
                              SELECT MAX(val) FROM the_table -- note below
                              )
            )
SELECT
      seq.val AS missing_sequence_value
FROM seq
      LEFT JOIN the_table t
                  ON seq.val = t.val
WHERE t.val IS NULL
ORDER BY
      missing_sequence_value
;
```

[This variation at SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71584/15/1)

Notable difference to SQL Server: you can use a subquery to limit the recursion

Also, Oracle documentation often refers to Subquery Factoring e.g.  [`subquery_factoring_clause::=`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) instead of CTE

---

Second is a variation on the use of connect by level as used by `a_horse_with_no_name`

[Level](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009261) is a pseudo column available in Oracle's [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) and the root of a hierarchy is 1. When using connect by level, by default this will commence at 1

For this variation I just wished to demonstrate that it does not need to be coupled with CTE's at all, and hence the syntax can be quite concise.

```
SELECT
      seq.val AS missing_sequence_value
FROM (
            SELECT
                  level - 1 AS val
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT max(val) FROM the_table)
      ) seq
      LEFT JOIN the_table t
                  ON seq.val = t.val
WHERE t.val IS NULL
ORDER BY
      missing_sequence_value
;
```

[This variation at SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#executionPlan)